# jQuery change "PLUS MINUS image"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to make a small code for changing the plus minus on click.

```
<!-- Plus -->
  <div class="plus">
  <img class="open" src="img/plus.png" alt="Open">
  </div>
  <!-- Plus end -->


$(".plus").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".navigation").slideToggle(100);
})
.toggle( function() {
    $(this).children("class").img("plus.png");
}, function() {
    $(this).children("class").img("minus.png");
});
```

Maybe i do something wrong...
Thank for any ideas

Comment: There is no `$.img()`, and the `.children('class')` selector would like to pick all `<class>` tags [which is unlikely to happen]. Moreover, this should be done in pure CSS, by giving different background-images to 2 different classes of same element [or better by spriting].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$('.plus').click(function(){
    $(this).children('img').toggle(0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XPBpm/3/